# How do I stop items in a renderUI block from resetting?

Tags: r, shiny

I've created a reprex for my shiny application that has one of two options from a renderUI output displayed, depending on other interactivity from the application.  I've included the interactivity with a simple radioButton input to show that this part is important.

My problem is that the manufacturer input resets whenever a different value than the initial one is chosen.  The entire renderUI block seems to be reset every time a different input$manu is chosen.  How would I keep the dependency between input$manu and input$model in these circumstances?

Here is the reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(radioButtons("word_or_select",
                          label = "print a word or show selections",
                          choices = c("word", "select"))),
    fluidRow(uiOutput("cascade"))
    
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    
    output$cascade <- renderUI({
        
        if(input$word_or_select == "word"){
            helpText("Here's your word")
        } else{
            tagList(
                column(3,
                       selectInput("manu",
                                   label = "manu",
                                   choices = unique(mpg$manufacturer),
                                   multiple = FALSE
                       )
                ),
                column(3,
                       selectInput("model",
                                   label = "model",
                                   choices = mpg %>%
                                       filter(manufacturer %in% input$manu) %>%
                                       distinct(model) %>% pull(model)
                       )
                )
            )
        }
        
    })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reactive (here `renderUI`) is re-evaluated every time one of its input changes (here `input$manu`).

You can either have to use 2 different `renderUI` to build "manu" and "model", or you can use `updateSelectInput` to populate model based on manu like this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$cascade <- renderUI({
    if(input$word_or_select == "word"){
      helpText("Here's your word")
    } else{
      tagList(
        column(3,
               selectInput("manu",
                           label = "manu",
                           choices = unique(mpg$manufacturer),
                           multiple = FALSE
               )
        ),
        column(3,
               selectInput("model",
                           label = "model",
                           choices = NULL
               )
        )
      )
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$manu, 
               if(!is.null(input$manu))
                  updateSelectInput(session, "model",
                                   choices = mpg %>%
                                     filter(manufacturer %in% input$manu) %>%
                                     distinct(model) %>% pull(model) ))
}
```

Comment: And the `updateXX` approach should be a bit faster than `renderUI` because then the update can be done client-side